# FormatException int.Parse() even when passing correct format string value

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, properties, startup, appsettings

I am trying to initialize the appsettings to FileUploadSetting object through startup using AddSingleton DI. Even though the value passed to int.Parse() method in different property just to access the converted value of AllowedFileSize is "3145728‬" then also it gives error as FormatException. What i am doing wrong ?

appsettings.json

```
"FileUploadSetting": {
    "AllowedExtensions": [ ".pdf", ".doc", ".docx" ],
    "StoredFilesPath": "Uploads/",
    "AllowedFileSize": "3145728‬" //in bytes

  },
```

Startup.cs

```
//FileUploadSetting
services.AddSingleton<WebApplication.Services.FileUpload.IFileUploadSetting>(Configuration.GetSection("FileUploadSetting").Get<WebApplication.Services.FileUpload.FileUploadSetting>());
```

FileUploadSetting.cs

```
public interface IFileUploadSetting
    {
        string[] AllowedExtensions { get; set; }
        string StoredFilesPath { get; set; }
        string AllowedFileSize { get; set; }
        int GetAllowedFileSize { get;}
    }
public class FileUploadSetting : IFileUploadSetting
    {
        public string[] AllowedExtensions { get; set; }
        public string StoredFilesPath { get; set; }
        public string AllowedFileSize { get; set; }

        public int GetAllowedFileSize
        {
            get
            {
                return int.Parse(AllowedFileSize);//**Error mention below even though when breakpoint is placed the value passed to it is "3145728‬"**
            }

        }
    }
```

Error

```
System.FormatException
  HResult=0x80131537
  Message=Input string was not in a correct format.
  Source=System.Private.CoreLib
  StackTrace:
   at System.Number.ThrowOverflowOrFormatException(ParsingStatus status, TypeCode type)
   at System.Number.ParseInt32(ReadOnlySpan`1 value, NumberStyles styles, NumberFormatInfo info)
   at System.Int32.Parse(String s)
   at Clanstech.Services.FileUpload.FileUploadSetting.get_GetAllowedFileSize() in C:\Users\admin\source\Workspaces\WebApplication\Services\FileUpload\FileUploadSetting.cs:line 18
```

[Screenshot For Reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xE9vs.png)

Comment: There's some junk after the `8` in `"AllowedFileSize": "3145728‬" //in bytes`. Delete the entire value in quotes then retype and you should be OK.

Comment: Yes you are right @JustinEzequiel . It worked . But how did you find out that there is junk value , because its invisible even when i copy the same value to notepad or other text editors .

Comment: Copied and pasted your sample into [dotnetfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/uNzBY7) and got the same error you were getting so I did some investigating.

Comment: @JustinEzequiel Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an invisible character at the end (after the 8).

You'll notice that the following evaluates to true:

```
AllowedFileSize[7] == '\u202c'
```

One approach could be

```
return int.Parse(AllowedFileSize.Trim('\u202c'));
```

But that's just a "quick" fix, and you'll likely just want to fix the json. Delete the whole value, including the double quotes and re-type those as well.
Your editor probably won't capture that hidden character if you do something like double click the value to edit (Visual Studio didn't when I tested this).

Comment: Yes you are right @Broots . It worked . But how did you find out that there is junk value , because its invisible even when i copy the same value to notepad or other text editors .

Comment: @AnujChauhan - I had a suspicion, so first thing I did was just copied the value from your post and called `"3145728‬".Length` in Visual Studio's interactive window (which returned 8). You would see that value in a hex editor though. It's not a printable character so a normal text editor won't show it.

Comment: Broots Waymb Thanks for the solution  !